# How can I create PostgreSQL function for I: 123 as O: One Two Three as well as Un Deux Trois?

Tags: sql, postgresql

How would one write a function in PostgreSQL to obtain a number in words?

**Input**: 123
**Output**: Un Deux Trois
One Two Three

**Input**: 123.00
**Output**: Un Deux Trois . Zéro Zéro
One Two Three . Zero Zero

I tried to create a function for French words but this is not it.

```
    Create or replace   FUNCTION ZeroToNine (dd_amt int)   
    RETURNS VARCHAR(50) 
    AS $$
    DECLARE fr_word VARCHAR(50);
     BEGIN

     fr_word:='';

       if dd_amt = 0 then   fr_word:='Zéro';
 
     elsif dd_amt = 1 then  fr_word:='Un';

     elsif dd_amt = 2 then  fr_word:='Deux';

     elsif dd_amt = 3 then  fr_word:='Trois';

     elsif dd_amt = 4 then    fr_word:='Quatre';

     elsif dd_amt = 5 then    fr_word:='Cinq';

     elsif dd_amt = 6 then    fr_word:='Six';

     elsif dd_amt = 7 then    fr_word:='Sept';

     elsif dd_amt = 8 then    fr_word:='Huit';

     elsif dd_amt = 9 then    fr_word:='Neuf';
        end if;
        end if;
```

Comment: You are not `RETURN`ing anything.

Answer (score 0):

This function will do the trick, but it takes a decimal as input, like your second example. It's using some array functions to handle the input and output:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ZeroToNine (dd_amt DECIMAL) 
RETURNS TEXT 
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS 
$$ 
DECLARE
    _content    TEXT[]  := string_to_array(CAST(dd_amt AS TEXT),NULL);
    _slice      TEXT;
    _output     TEXT[];
BEGIN
    FOREACH  _slice IN ARRAY _content
    LOOP
        _output := _output || 
            CASE _slice
                WHEN '0' THEN 'Zéro'
                WHEN '1' THEN 'Un'
                WHEN '2' THEN 'Deux'
                WHEN '3' THEN 'Trois'
                WHEN '4' THEN 'Quatre'
                WHEN '5' THEN 'Cinq'
                WHEN '6' THEN 'Six'
                WHEN '7' THEN 'Sept'
                WHEN '8' THEN 'Huit'
                WHEN '9' THEN 'Neuf'
                WHEN '.' THEN '.'
            END CASE;
    END LOOP;
    
    RETURN array_to_string(_output, ' ');                                   
END;                    
$$;

SELECT ZeroToNine (01203.01);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for this! I want to ask if it's possible to use (trunc(dd_amt, 2) or something else somewhere? Because to the original script/code it is returning One Two Three . Zero Zero Zero Zero Zero Zero

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ZeroToNine(dd_amt numeric)
  RETURNS text AS
$$
  DECLARE res text;
BEGIN
  
SELECT string_agg(t.dtext, ' ' ORDER BY nums.ord)
FROM (
  SELECT * FROM (VALUES
     ('.', '.'), ('1', 'One'), ('2', 'Two'),
     ('3', 'Three'), ('4', 'Four'), ('5', 'Five'),
     ('6', 'Six'), ('7', 'Seven'), ('8', 'Eight'),
     ('9', 'Nine'),('0', 'Zero')) dnames(digit, dtext)
) t JOIN 
  UNNEST(regexp_split_to_array(dd_amt::text, '')) WITH ORDINALITY AS nums(digit, ord) 
ON t.digit = nums.digit
INTO res;
RETURN res;
  
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

[See demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/MEehlkmo)

> The [regexp_split_to_array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html) returns its result as an array of text.

Here, the result of this function for (123.00) will be `{1,2,3,.,0,0}`.

Then use the `unnest` function with `ordinality` on the resulting array from the `regexp_split_to_array` function. The use of ordinality is to get the correct order of input number digits for the next step. The output of this step will be:

```
digit   ord
1       1
2       2
3       3
.       4
0       5
0       6
```

Now, we join this result with the subquery t to get the corresponding digit text. To group digit texts in a single text we use the `string_agg` function ordered by the order we got from the ordinality. The final result of this will be:

`One Two Three . Zero Zero`